# `unexpected end of file` after a while loop

Tags: shell

The entirety of my Openbox autostart file is as follows:

```
# Compositor
picom &

# Korean input
ibus-daemon -dr &

# Screensaver
xscreensaver -no-splash &

# Wallpaper
while true; do
    nitrogen --random --set-auto
    sleep 3600
end
```

But when I login, it appears as though only `picom` was run successfully.

Running `bash ~/.config/openbox/autostart` from a terminal indicates

```
/home/max/.config/openbox/autostart: line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

so I think something is wrong with my while loop, but what?

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` like in the Bourne shell where that syntax initially comes from, `while` loops end with `done`:

```bash
# Wallpaper
while true; do
    nitrogen --random --set-auto
    sleep 3600
done
```

What's happening is that the shell is finding the start of the `while` loop and then reads ahead, searching for its end. It reaches the end of the file before finding the terminating `done` keyword and complains.  Hence "unexpected end of file".

Comment: That does it. Thank you.

Comment: @Max please see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers you can also accept an answer if it's ok for you.

Comment: It is customary to wait 24 hours to accept an answer in order to encourage people from various time zones to respond

Comment: @Max There is no such custom, but it's perfectly fine to accept one answer first and then change one's mind and accept another.

Comment: FWIW and for completeness, `end` is used to terminate `while` loops in `csh`, `tcsh` and `fish`. `zsh` has short forms that don't require the `do` and `done`, reminiscent of `rc`'s `while (cond) cmd`'s ones.